# How to store user-styled HTML partial?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a partial HTML, which is a dashboard with widgets on them. The user can move them around the page, delete and add new ones. However, at the moment, when I reload the page, logout and login or something their "work" is lost.

What is the best way to store this? I was thinking of adding "id's" to the div which contains the widget, with every widget div having a different id obviously. Then everytime a widget is moved, added or deleted, an array containing all the ID's (in the widget placement order) is changed depending on what happens with the widge and UPDATED in the database.

Is there a better way though?

Comment: Sorting in a database seems perfectly reasonable if the order of the widgets needs to be retained afterwards.

Comment: So my idea is acceptable? Store their IDs in the DB?